# Servers for hire which use ATI graphics cards

Tags: linux

I'm trying to find servers I can hire which use ATI graphics cards. Any ideas? Googling brings up nothing but there must be some companies out there which offer this.

Note, nvidia cards aren't suitable.

Thanks.

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic on the StackExchange network.

Comment: Try joining [ServerFault Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127/the-comms-room) so we can get a better idea of what you're after.

Comment: ...although it would likely be an idea to contact your local decicated server hoster and ask if they use ATI cards.

Comment: Nobody does this. Primarily because AMD's OpenCL implementation requires the program to be running under the local X session, rather than simply on the computer with the GPU. So you can forget about mining Bitcoins on someone else's computer...

Answer (score 1):

Call your preferred server vendor (Dell, HP, IBM, whoever). Give them your requirements. Then, check your inbox for a quote.

Comment: He's looking to rent one (like getting a VPS for $x/month), not buy one.

Comment: Huh, well that wasn't clear